# Is it correct to say "the core" or "the nucleus" of an exhibition?

Tags: word-choice

This is my first participation, and I thank in advance all of you who will try to help me here.
As I asked in the title, is it correct to say "the core" or "the nucleus" of an exhibition?
I mean a group of specific items presented in an exhibition. It is not a section, which I think is something more general and in which may exist different "nuclei". 
The use of the word "nucleus" here comes from a direct translation from the Portuguese, "um dos núcleos da exposição", for instance.

Thank you all again,
Isabel

Comment: Could you be more specific about the idea you want to express? Please provide an example of an exhibition, what items are included in the core (and why), and what items you deem to be outside the core. Also, consider deleting the question here and asking on [ell.se] instead — the question would be better received there.

Answer (score 2):

In British English many would refer to *core* or *[nucleus](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/nucleus)* of an exhibition as being the "Focal Point" of the exhibition, meaning the main point to which attention is drawn. You could also say "Centre" but that would generally be treated as the literal centre of an exhibition in a geometric sense ie. an equal distance from all sides of the exhibition.

Answer (score 1):

Many people would say the center or the main part of the exhibition.

Answer (score 0):

It should also be remembrered that "core" derives from the French "coeur" meaning heart, which is used frequently in a figurative sense.

Comment: Or perhaps from "body" ... http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/core#Etymology_1

Answer (score 0):

The word "core" is often used metaphorically, as in "ART VIEW; Hypnotic Images From the Core of Islam" a review in the The New York Times that ran in 1993. "Nucleus" is perfectly correct also although less frequently applied. "Heart" would be another synonym.